# How to switch connection between cloud and local network in ESP8266

Tags: arduino, cloud, iot, esp8266, aws-iot

I would like to understand it is possible to switch the ESP8266 connection between the cloud and WiFi LAN.

[image]

There are two paths to control the sonoff switch, connected to a wifi router. In case the phone is connected to the router, Path 1 acts as  LAN network and ESP8266 can be controlled even without internet. In case I am not at home and would like to control the switch remotely via cloud, path 2 would be followed. Thus, I could get the best of both worlds.

From all the examples that i have seen so far ESP8266 could be operated in only one mode at one point of time, either Lan or cloud (both via the WiFi router).

So kindly help me with the switching code/logic, that will wait to work upon the commands provided via LAN mode if there are none left. Now it should work upon the instructions after switching to cloud mode and finally return to LAN mode after sometime and so on.

Comment: Any more feedback required here?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons your Sonoff device should **not** be reachable from the internet directly - ever. It should only be accessible within your local (home) network. That's your path 1.

To enable path 2 - without affecting the Sonoff device at all - you need a way to build a [*VPN*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) from your smartphone to your local network. For the node it will look like all traffic is coming from your local network even though you are actually connecting into it from remote.

A fairly simple and cost-effective way to achieve this is to run [PiVPN](https://pivpn.dev/) on a Raspberry Pi. See e.g. this video for instructions: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=15VjDVCISj0